# How to solving : CSS selector “:active” not working?

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover

I'm very confused, because :hover selector was working normaly, but :active not working.

scenario:

first : sample.com/game when click link box game of different ID (ex: ID 1-101) with every box use css

```css
#selec{background-color:white;-moz-border-radius: 10px;-webkit-border-radius: 10px;border-radius: 10px;}
```

when click one of box ID go to sample.com/game?id=100

I was successfully for hover

```css
#selec:hover{background-color:blue;}
```

but i want to active with color background, when box is active (box ID 100 with red background and other still white because box 100 was active)

```css
#selec:active{background-color:blue;}
```

But didn't successfull, WHY????? I still confused for this.

This php file:

```css
<a href="?game=<?php echo $ID;?>"><div id="selec"><div class="text"><p><?php echo $text; ?></p></div></div></a>
```

Anyone help me to solveing this? thanks
*`$text` for give name in box for example box ID 100 is Game RPG

Answer (score 9):

The `:active` CSS pseudo class works on all elements... *however* it only works on links (e.g. `<a>` elements) if you are not rendering in **Standards Mode in Internet Explorer**.

thus it won't work on your `<div>` in IE, if you don't have a DOCTYPE set.

Add this to the top of your HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
```

The order that each pseudo class is defined matters too... (to ensure they all "override" the previous)... just remember that:

"<kbd>L</kbd>ord <kbd>V</kbd>adar's <kbd>H</kbd>andle <kbd>F</kbd>ormerly <kbd>A</kbd>nakin"

```css
a:link    {color:blue;}
a:visited {color:green;}
a:hover   {color:red;}
a:focus   {color:orange;}
a:active  {color:yellow;}
```

Note: Thanks to @BoltClock for indicating the error on the W3Schools site here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp that indicates it is only available on links. (This is no longer correct in modern browsers (rendering in standards mode))

Note 2: W3C indicates that :active pseudo class was added to all elements in CSS 2.1, it was only on links in CSS 1.0:
"Note. Also note that in CSS1, the ':active' pseudo-class only applied to links."
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#pseudo-class-selectors

Comment: `:active` is not specified to only apply to `a` elements, or only "links". No idea where W3Schools pulled that idea from.

Comment: @scunliffe : Thank you for your respond. But its doesn't effected. Any another idea???

Comment: @BoltClock you are correct.  Modern browsers do support it on all elements (though there is a catch which I'm updating the answer with)

Comment: Ah yes, CSS1. They (W3Schools) really should get that page updated, then.